# I have two lists. list1 as keys, list2 as values. How to appendix a list of values to the same keys in the list1?

Tags: list, loops, dictionary

list1 = [A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

expected output:{A:[1,2,3],B:[4,5,6],C:[7,8,9]}

This is what I would like to do. However, I got stuck when I append different lists of values. 
Here's my code:

```
g = []
for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    if list1[i] == list1[i+1]:
        g.append(list2[i+1])
    else:
        continue
print(g)
```

and the output is:[1,2,3,5,6,8,9]. How can I do so I can get separate lists as [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Regarding the phrasing, I believe you are actually looking for building a map based on two lists. If that's correct, I suggest you to explain how you want to build the map before providing the example. Also, if you target a specific language, you can mention it in the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below using a dictionary :

```
list1 = ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

output = {}
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] not in output:
        output[list1[i]] = [list2[i]]
    else:
        output[list1[i]].append(list2[i])

print(output)
```